# Select based on multiple ID's in the same column

Tags: sql, join, select

I have two SQL tables already built (not by me) :

One table that has all the ingredients with ID's assigned to them :

```
IngredientID | IngredientName
1            | Milk
2            | Eggs
3            | Flower
```

and the second table that has finished products that have reference to ingredientID in the ProductIngredients column but no the product name and they are built like this :

```
ProductID | ProductName | ProductIngredients
1         | Tomato Soup | NULL
2         | Pancakes    | ;1;2;3
3         | Omlette     | ;1;2
```

If they don't have any reference then its written NULL, and if they have, then they start with a ";" symbol and every ingredient is divided by a ";" symbol.

My goal is to join those two tables and make a select statement that returns me, instead of the ID's of the other column, the actual names of the used ingredients like this :

```
ProductID | ProductName | ProductIngredients
1         | Tomato Soup | 
2         | Pancakes    | Milk, Eggs, Flower
3         | Omlette     | Milk, Eggs
```

**Can anyone help out with this?**

Comment: Fix your data model!  Do not store lists of numbers as strings.  That is just the wrong way to store values in a database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a left join of Products to ProductIngredients and group by product:

```
select p.ProductID, p.ProductName,
  group_concat(i.IngredientName order by i.IngredientID) ProductIngredients
from Products p left join Ingredients i
on concat(p.ProductIngredients, ';') like concat('%;', i.IngredientID,';%')
group by p.ProductID, p.ProductName
```

The function `group_concat()` works in MySql but you can find similar functions to other databases.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gbpbR6ZhsLtRN7gq9YCh6u/1).
Results:

```
| ProductID | ProductName | ProductIngredients |
| --------- | ----------- | ------------------ |
| 1         | Tomato Soup |                    |
| 2         | Pancakes    | Milk,Eggs,Flower   |
| 3         | Omlette     | Milk,Eggs          |
```

Comment: If you run your query multiple times it will shift the order of the ingredients in your demo.  Edit: Excellent! That's definitely better than what I was thinking about doing and will return the correct order every time now.

Comment: @Dresden this is solved with ORDER BY... inside group_concat(). I edited.